# How to delete folder with files using Google Storage REST api?

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to delete `_$folder$` from Google Storage using their REST api. I have tried so far `headerserver.com/testestset/*`, `headerserver.com/testestset`, `headerserver.com/testestset_$folder$` but neither seem to work when there are any files in the folder.

The only approach I came up so far is to `foreach` all objects under the `_$folder$` before attempting to delete it, however, this is highly inefficient.

In a worst scenario: is it possible to batch/delete more than one file per one request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no other way other than deleting all objects withig the directory or `_$folder$` object.

Answer (score 1):

It's been 4 years, and they still don't give a proper API for this.

For you who still need a work around, here is an option.

This example is to remove a *parent folder*, its *nested folders*, and all of their *contents*

```
<?php

/**
 * Delete nested folders for Google Cloud Storage
 */

class ClassName {

    /** @var Google_Service_Storage $storageService */
    public $storageService;

    /** @var string $bucket */
    public $bucket = '';

    /**
     * Remove an object
     *
     * @param string $objectPath
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function removeObject($objectPath) {
        // validator
        try {
            if (!$this->storageService->objects->get($this->bucket, $objectPath)) {
                // log error
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            // leave this empty
        }

        // remove action
        try {
            $this->storageService->objects->delete($this->bucket, $objectPath);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            // log error
            return false;
        }
        // log success

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified container
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function removeContainer($path) {
        $c = array();
        $c['delimiter'] = '/';
        if (!empty($path) && $path != '/') {
            $c['prefix'] = $path;
        }
        $objects = null;

        // validator
        try {
            $objects = $this->storageService->objects->listObjects($this->bucket, $c);
            if (empty($objects)) {
                if (!$this->storageService->objects->get($this->bucket, $path)) {
                    // log error
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            // leave this empty
        }

        // remove action
        try {
            if (empty($objects)) {
                $this->storageService->objects->delete($this->bucket, $path);
            } else {
                /**
                 * Process files first
                 */
                $files = $objects->getItems();
                if (!empty($files)) {
                    foreach ($files as $file) {
                        $this->removeObject($file->getName());
                    }
                }
                /**
                 * And folders later
                 */
                $folders = $objects->getPrefixes();
                if (!empty($folders)) {
                    foreach ($folders as $folder) {
                        $this->removeContainer($folder);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            // log error
            return false;
        }
        // log success

        return true;
    }

}
```

This is how it's logged in database, to explain the recursive process.

[image: recursive folders delete]

If you are curious why *empty-folder*s came out twice in the log for `file_remove` and `directory_remove`, this `$objects = $this->driver->objects->listObjects($this->bucket, $c);` part listed the folder's name back into `$files = $objects->getItems();`,

may be because it's not a physical folder, but rather an empty file that represents as a folder.